No such file or directory error for entrypoint.sh file in docker
I am following a course and currently stuck on this part of it.
After starting up Docker container (that says it is installed correctly when running localhost) I get:  service "movies" is not running
Folder structure:

docker-compose.yaml:
# version: '3.8'

services:
  movies:
    build: ./TestDrivenIO
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./TestDrivenIO/:/usr/src/TestDrivenIO/
    ports:
      - 8009:8000
    env_file:
      - ./TestDrivenIO/.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - movies-db
  movies-db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:  # create a volume and bind directory to the container
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:  # added ENV key to define a name for default DB & credentials
      - POSTGRES_USER=movies
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=movies
      - POSTGRES_DB=movies_dev

volumes:
  postgres_data:

Dockerfile:
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11.2-slim-buster

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/TestDrivenIO

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# updated
# install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install netcat gcc postgresql \
  && apt-get clean

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# new
# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/TestDrivenIO/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/TestDrivenIO/entrypoint.sh

# add app
COPY . .

# new
# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/TestDrivenIO/entrypoint.sh"]

How can I determine the issue here? I don't see any way to check logs, it SEEMS as if I've done everything right, but I don't understand why it says it's not running.
Here is what it looks like when checking processes:

After some additional research, I have found that for some reason, the entrypoint.sh file is not being copied over.


You definitely shouldn't COPY to a folder that is later mounted as volume, unless you really know what you're doing and why. Now you have a volume that replaces whatever you copied in the Dockerfile before. Why is that volume there? Usually we try to build an image that contains everything necessary, volumes are for persistent data. Are you trying to make some kind of hot-reload container?

As mentioned by STerliakov the content of your volume replaces the entrypoint.sh copied over to your image. My guess is that the permissions of the entrypoint.sh file on your volume isn't set properly to make it executable.

After looking into EVERYTHING I possibly could ... I went back and commented out the Dockerfile entrypoint and below section. It worked. So this one change was the problem.
I then deleted the entrypoint file then created a new with the same content. Uncommented the stuff. And it worked! I had changed the permissions locally on the file like the class said to, but apparently this caused an issue with copying the file over.
UPDATE:  Nope, I was mistaken. I just never uncommented the section again. It's still not working.
